# Execute large code snippet of string on one line

Tags: python

I'm not able to find an answer to this for some reason - I'm looking to execute a large string code snippet as python code

For example the following code:

```
def multiply_num_by_5(num): 
    return 5*num 
multiply_num_by_5(4)
```

And now as one line:
`exec("def multiply_num_by_5(num): return 5*num print(multiply_num_by_5(4))")`

However this returns a syntax error.

Is this possible to do (without modifying the string of code itself)? Is there a common parsing technique / library which allows running such code?

NOTE: I'm aware I can run the following. Here the `print` line is correctly indented. However this wouldn't be 'one line':

```
exec('''def multiply_num_by_5(num): return 5*num 
print(multiply_num_by_5(4))''')
```

Comment: What syntax error is it producing because I just ran the code on google colab and it worked.

Comment: One line: `exec('''def multiply_num_by_5(num): return 5*num\nprint(multiply_num_by_5(4))''')`. Line break is `"\n"`, tab is `"\t"`.

Comment: Are you really willing to execute some random code from wherever?

Comment: @DwightFoster it points at the start of the `print` line and just says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` - so for me it's picking up the invalid indentation. I'm running on Jupyter notebooks

Comment: @JustinEzequiel the string line of code cannot be manipulated, so any processing must be done outside of the string. Yes the code I'll be running will be safe - I've seen the security implications but they don't apply to my scenario

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a return character `\n` works for me

```
exec("def multiply_num_by_5(num): return 5*num\nprint(multiply_num_by_5(4))")
```

Comment: Hi - sorry I should state, the string line cannot be manipulated

Comment: @solarflare so how are you planning to fix its syntax error?

Comment: @tboschi that would be the question! Other languages can be run in 'minimised' form (such as javascript) - of course the runtime of python is entirely different, but that is the question essentially - is there not a solution?

Comment: @solarflare Yes, there is - to fix the syntax error in the string... I don't understand how else you expect to execute it

Comment: So the requirement is to run invalid code? No, that's the end of it then, in any language.

Comment: @Tomerikoo the scenario is that a snippet of python code is obtained as a single line of string. The solution I'm looking for is the automate the syntax fixing and be able to execute the code, through some parsing technique, library etc...

Comment: @couka how would it be invalid code after it's been fixed?

Comment: I agree that the string must have a correct syntax

Comment: I can't think of a library that does that. I can't think of a reason for one to exist...

Comment: You can't fix it without changing it. Indentation and line breaks are a fundamental part of pythons syntax and it's been removed here.

Comment: Ok appreciate the answers. It doesn't seem very far-fetched - it's clear from the code snippet there needs to be a new line after a return statement. May not be true for absolutely every scenario, however I would guess 99% of return statements expect a new line afterwards. Therefore I was expected there to be a library which can automate correct syntax along these lines of reasoning..

Comment: For the trivial example here, sure. But the quest was about 'a large code snippet'. For 'a large code snippet' there's is a ridiculously large number of possible indentations and a still large subset of those are syntactically correct. Only one (or few) of them does what the original code did, though.